# Index as servlet, rest as static content

Tags: g-wan

I picked up G-WAN only a while back and I'm trying to figure out how to make the index use a specific servlet while also having static content available.

*I moved `index.html` to `index_old.html` so I wouldn't have any conflicts.*

I placed the following into a handler.

```
xbuf_t *read_xbuf = (xbuf_t*)get_env(argv, READ_XBUF);
xbuf_replfrto(read_xbuf, read_xbuf->ptr, read_xbuf->ptr + 16, "/", "/?hello");
```

After restarting gwan, I saw `Hello, ANSI C!` just like I desired.

However, I noticed that all other contents no longer loaded, even the 404 page was different!

So, then I had a thought, that this seemed to be doing string substitution, rather than precise matching.

```
xbuf_t *read_xbuf = (xbuf_t*)get_env(argv, READ_XBUF);
xbuf_replfrto(read_xbuf, read_xbuf->ptr, read_xbuf->ptr + 16, "/", "/?");
```

Now, when hitting `/`, I saw a 404, and `/hello`, I saw the servlet again. So, this does not seem to be the solution I am looking for.

Again, I just want `/` to hit a specific servlet of my designation, and for all other requests to not be effected by this one rule.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It appears that a similar solution is presented in 
[G-WAN handler rewriting solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398849/g-wan-handler-rewriting-solution/15443785#15443785)

Using that, I derived the following code that allows not only the index to be generated, but also any additional query strings.

```
char *szRequest = (char*)get_env(argv, REQUEST);
if(strncmp(szRequest, "GET / ", 6) == 0){
        xbuf_t *read_xbuf = (xbuf_t*)get_env(argv, READ_XBUF);
        xbuf_replfrto(read_xbuf, read_xbuf->ptr, read_xbuf->ptr + 16, "/", "/!hello");
}else if(strncmp(szRequest, "GET /?", 6) == 0){
        xbuf_t *read_xbuf = (xbuf_t*)get_env(argv, READ_XBUF);
        xbuf_replfrto(read_xbuf, read_xbuf->ptr, read_xbuf->ptr + 16, "/?", "/!hello&");
}
```

As seen above, I had to move to `!` to avoid conflict. This means I had to add the following in the `init()` function.

```
u8 *query_char = (u8*)get_env(argv, QUERY_CHAR);
*query_char = '!';
```

I am able to access `/` and `/?blah` without issue, while still being able to access a file like `100.html` without getting a servlet 404.

*It seems like any other similar bindings to a URL while not blocking off the rest of the directory can be made easier with a macro.*